# ASP.NET: error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to deploy a local webpage and I'm getting this error. I know this is caused by ASP.NET not being installed correctly on my computer, but I'm not sure how to fix that. I've been looking up answers on Google and here, and most of them are from 5-12 years ago. In any case, the solutions I've tried haven't worked.

I've tried installing ASP.NET from the Command Prompt and turning on the ASP.NET features through appwiz.cpl. All the other solutions are old and don't seem to apply to now.

Here  is the  code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 593px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            height: 476px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Homepage" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
        <table class="auto-style3">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkEntertain" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/entertain.png" ImageWidth="100%" NavigateUrl="~/Default2.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkTools" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/tools.png" ImageWidth="100%">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkTeaching" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/teaching.png" ImageWidth="100%">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkMyLMS" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Filled Ranged Colour@4x.png" ImageWidth="100%" NavigateUrl="https://mylmsft.institution.africa/my/">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your starting line of page from

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

to:

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

remove under score from beginning of page name inside Inherits tag

Comment: Hmm I don't think so, since "_Default" is the name of the class too.